# Getting firebase data sorted by child and retrieving parent

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

So basically I am trying to make a leaderboard for my game and so I structured my database like this:

`{
  "users" : {
    "feshfjhgfj" : {
      "email" : "gfdgfdg",
      "likes" : 0,
      "password" : "gdhfghg"
    }
  }
}`

The accounts are created for each individual when they start the game so I do not know the username on the other end of the device. I'm retrieving data like this :

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
reference.Child("users").OrderByChild("likes").LimitToFirst(1).ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;

void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.DatabaseError != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }

    Debug.Log(DataBase.userID);

    Debug.Log(args.Snapshot.Children);
}
```

And I do not know how to retrieve the username to display it on the screen after the sorting occured. All I get is an enumerable object which I do not know how to handle;

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I just needed to go

```
var a = args.Snapshot.Children;
a.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();

Debug.Log(a.GetEnumerator().Current.Key);
```

And this returns the value of the node that i wanted.